# Matching groups of nested parentheses using Regex and Pushdown-Automata

Tags: c#, regex, pushdown-automaton

I'm working on a c# regular expression that can match nested constructions (parentheses in this case) as well as arbitrary operators (a '|' character in this case).

I've gotten started by using a push-down automata as described [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/21080/In-Depth-with-RegEx-Matching-Nested-Constructions).

What I have so far:

```
String pattern = @"
(?# line 01) \(
(?# line 02) (?>
(?# line 03) \( (?<DEPTH>)
(?# line 04) |
(?# line 05) \) (?<-DEPTH>)
(?# line 06) |
(?# line 07) .?
(?# line 08) )*
(?# line 09) (?(DEPTH)(?!))
(?# line 10) \)
";

var source = "((Name1| Name2) Blah) | (Name3 ( Blah | Blah))";

var matches = Regex.Matches(source, pattern,
  RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace);
matches.Dump();
```

Yields the following results:

```
// ((Name1| Name2) Blah)
// (Name3 ( Blah | Blah))
```

Desired results:

```
// ((Name1| Name2) Blah)
// |
// (Name3 ( Blah | Blah))
```

*Note:* There may or may not be any operators between the groups. For example, the source may look like "((Name1| Name2) Blah) (Name3 ( Blah | Blah))"

Comment: Regex is not a good candidate for this. I would suggest parsing it yourself or using a parsing library. That is, assuming your nested parenthesis structure can be more complex than what you've given.

Comment: @SimonWhitehead Yes, I'm aware that a parser is a better way to go for maintainability. I plan to use Antlr for a more permanant solution. Thank you for your input!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this: *(just adding `|\|` at the end)*

```
\((?>\((?<DEPTH>)|\)(?<-DEPTH>)|.?)*(?(DEPTH)(?!))\)|\|
```