# Regex nested parentheses not working in one case

Tags: c#, regex, visual-studio, .net-4.5.2

Using C# [Grouping Constructs in Regular Expressions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bs2twtah(v=vs.110).aspx) one can match the content inside nested parentheses as shown by [this response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17202517/1232087). Following code correctly returns `(b/(2c))` and `(abc)` :

```
st = "Test(b/(2c)) some (abc) test.";
foreach (Match mt in Regex.Matches(st, @"\((?>\((?<DEPTH>)|\)(?<-DEPTH>)|.?)*(?(DEPTH)(?!))\)"))
{
    Console.WriteLine(mt.Value);
}
```

However, when I change the pattern to `@"(?<=/)\((?>\((?<DEPTH>)|\)(?<-DEPTH>)|.?)*(?(DEPTH)(?!))\)"` by just adding `(?<=/)` before the above pattern to get only the parentheses that are preceded by `/` I expected to get only `(2c)` but I am getting `(2c))` with an extra `)`. **What I'm missing?** Note: If my input string is `Test(b)/(2c) some (abc) test.` then my new pattern correctly returns `(2c)` only.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `*` character is [greedy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2301285/what-do-lazy-and-greedy-mean-in-the-context-of-regular-expressions), and it will match as much as possible, which is why the second `)` character is matched.

To avoid this, you could either change `.` to `[^)]` to match all non `)` characters:

```
Regex.Matches(st, @"(?<=\/)\((?>\((?<DEPTH>)|\)(?<=-DEPTH>)|[^)])*(?(DEPTH)(?!))\)")
```

It would match `(2c)` - [example](https://regex101.com/r/wL3hE5/1).

---

Alternatively, you could just add `?` after `*` in `(?<=-DEPTH>)|.)*?` so that `*` is lazy and `.` will be matched as few times as possible.

```
Regex.Matches(st, @"(?<=\/)\((?>\((?<DEPTH>)|\)(?<=-DEPTH>)|.)*?(?(DEPTH)(?!))\)")
```

It would match `(2c)` as well - [example](https://regex101.com/r/hH0jN4/1).

Comment: Your both suggestions work. Thank you for explaining your solution a bit - it was the most important part for me. I replaced my pattern with your first solution on other cases where I'm using more complex nested parentheses and it works there as well.