# How to extract java method parameters with regex

Tags: java, python, regex, python-3.x

I'm writing a Python script to parse Java classes from a backend service in order to extract necessary information. One of the things I need is to extract the request parameter from a java method.

```
public\s+[\w<>\[\]]+\s+(\w+)\s*\(([^{]+)(^(@ApiParam(.*)\))|^(@PathParam(.*))|^(@QueryParam(.*))|(@\w+\s+)?)((\w+)\s+(\w+))
```

Is what I got so far... It already gives me the method parameters in the brackets () however I cannot filter out the @ApiParam and @QueryParam annotations.

```
/*Some annotations*/
public PortfolioSuggestion calculatePortfolioSuggestion(
        @ApiParam(required = true,
                  value = "Request containing the answers which were answered by the user and an\n" +
                          "investment for which suggestion should be calculated")
        @Valid @NotNull PortfolioSuggestionRequest portfolioSuggestionRequest,
        @ApiParam(value = "The optional product key")
        @QueryParam("product") ProductType productType)
        throws SuggestionsCalculationException {
```

The request parameter is always the first parameter which is **not** annotated with @ApiParam or @QueryParam. In this case my target would be **PortfolioSuggestionRequest** and **portfolioSuggestionRequest**. The annotations @Valid and @NotNull are always optional and could be omitted

Comment: Don't use regexp to parse code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TL;DR : Regexp are not powerful enough for your usecase

Any regexp is equivalent to a [Deterministic finite automaton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deterministic_finite_automaton).

Regexps are not always suited to parse code. It sometimes requires to have a [Pushdown automaton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pushdown_automaton) which regexp doesn't provide. You might want to look into [ANTLR](https://www.antlr.org/) which is full feature language parser.

See this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17202321/matching-groups-of-nested-parentheses-using-regex-and-pushdown-automata) for a similar example.

[Here](https://github.com/antlrjavaparser/antlr-java-parser) is some github repo aiming at parsing java using ANTLR.